# Como hago para que me responda algo que esta oculto

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Quiero tener un script donde después de un tiempo el haga esta acción.

```
<input id="sendThis" type="number" name="result" value="127605">
```

Y una vez puesto ese valor lo mande a este botón a continuación.

```
<button id="submitButton" type="submit" form="form1">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido, te invito a leer [ask] y checar el [tour], si nos pudieras compartir algún avance y dudas estaría genial.

Comment: No puedes solo cambiar el tipo en tu código html?

Comment: lo que pasa es que es un html de una pagina que no es mia, lo puedo hacer manual pero cada vez que refresco la pagina debo aparecer en elemento y meter el valor para enviarlo

Answer (score 0):

Con javascript buscas el elemento y le cambias el tipo con:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('sendThis').type = 'text';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya pude agregar el elemento oculto que apareciera, pero ahora quiero que cada cierto tiempo haga click en este boton

< button id="submitButton" type="submit" form="form1">SUBMIT

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a tu 2a pregunta:

```
setInterval(Intervalo, 1000);

function Intervalo() {
 $("#submitButton").click();
}
```

el tiempo es en milisegundos, cada cuanto necesitas que se ejecute

Puedes leer mas de esto aqui:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: muchas gracias ya resolvi mi duda, son unos genios!

Comment: No se te olvide marcar las respuestas